# Configure a custom gradle plugin task based on a condition that is a plugin property

Tags: gradle

I am writing a custom plugin that contains a copy task. The task is supposed to fetch either a wsdl file or a zip containing wsdl and xsds from a maven repository.  In the case of the zip file it will use ziptree to expand the files.

When this is done, another task will use wsimport to create a client jar from these files.

My current attempt is to use a plugin boolean property to differentiate.  The following code is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
void addTasks(Project project) {
  project.task('downloadWSDL', type: Copy) {
    if (project.wsimport.zipped) {
      from { project.configurations.wsdl.collect { project.zipTree(it) }}
      into { project.wsimport.wsdlDir }
    } else {
      from { project.configurations.wsdl }
      into { project.wsimport.wsdlDir }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that project.wsimport.zipped is not set (I suppose false) in the configuration phase.  I have tried to put it in a closure, but it seems to then still do the zipped path even though the property is set to false.

**How can I configure a task like this based on a condition?**

**Will a working solution function as expected when checking if it is up-to-date?**

I have thought an alternative approach might be to have 2 different tasks and modify the dependsOn of a depending class dynamically, but I suspect it will run into a similar problem.

Thank you.

Comment: This is what Project.afterEvaluate can help with.

Comment: Thanks I just found it in a related question, trying it out now...

Comment: afterEvaluate works like a charm on the task although it leads to a new challenge.  Since the task is now added after evaluation, how can configure another task to depend on it?  I have tried doing someting like build.dependsOn downloadWSDL inside and outside of a afterEvaluated, but nothing works.  Maybe I'm just not referring to the task correctly.